# Kinesis Analytics overlapping sliding window

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Is it possible to define a window with sliding interval? E.g. I need every 10 sec calculate sum over last 30 sec? Does Kinesis Analytics SQL support such type of sliding windows with overlaps?

Answer (score 0):

I think Hopping window stands for your neeeds [Microsoft documentation - Hopping window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/hopping-window-azure-stream-analytics)

Like :

```
SELECT SUM(my_thing) my_thing_sum
FROM my_table TIMESTAMP BY my_field_date
GROUP BY my_group
HoppingWindow(seconds, 30, 10)
```